# When loading a new view with an AJAX call on an existing page, how can I display existing php variables in it?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

In CodeIgniter, I have a web page which is displaying clients. A certain view `clients.php` is listing clients in a table. It displays the clients like this:

```
<?php 
foreach ($clients as $client) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $client->companyname ?></td>
    <td><?= $client->city ?></td>
    <td><?= $client->country ?></td>
    <td><?= $client->vat ?></td>
    <td><? <button class="edit-button" data-entityid="<?= $client->id ?>">edit</button></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

As you can see above, I have an edit button for each client. Clicking on a button does an AJAX call as shown below:

```
$('.edit-button').click(function(){
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'modalloader/editclient/' + this.dataset.entityid,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.modal-content').html('loading...');
            },
            success: function(result){
                $('.modal-content').html(result);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $('.modal-content').html('failed');
            }
        });
});
```

Right now, I am loading the data of the specific client again from the database through my model when I call the method `modalloader/editclient/clientid`, but in fact I have this data already available on the page (because of the view `clients.php`). Therefore I was wondering if I can instead grab it from the object `$clients` which I already have on my web page.

Right now, if I do a `var_dump($clients);` on the view that I loaded dynamically with the AJAX call to `modalloader/editclient/clientid` it's showing a `null` object.

Comment: By the time your original HTML gets to the client's browser, the `$clients` variable in PHP is gone. It's not in the HTML, and it's certainly not in the PHP that's handling the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You can return $clients variable from controller like json and after that set it to js variable. 
Like this:

```
<script>
    var clients = <?php echo $clients ?>;
<script>
```

After that you can use this variable in your script

Comment: That's actually a good point your making there. Then I can take all that particular client's data from the js var and print it using js instead of php. Thanks!